# Trouble understanding only one way implication truth

Tags: logic

I'm having a trouble understanding the concept. Can you give me a math example where $P\Rightarrow Q$ Is true but $P\Leftrightarrow Q$ is false? Thank you.

Comment: $\,\big(1 = -1\big) \implies \big(2=2\big)\;$ is true, but the converse is false.

Comment: If the moon is made of cheese, then what @dxiv said is true.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, everything, be it true or false, follows from a falsehood (assuming the law of the excluded middle holds).

Comment: Protip: The "official" name for this fallacy is "affirming the consequent."  Google that and you'll get loads of examples, many of which have relatively little to do with math.

Comment: "If it is Tuesday then I will go to the gym."  This is very different from "I only go the the gym on Tuesday".  The important thing to remember in x => y is that it really only works when x is true.  If x is not true then the statement doesn't apply so who knows whether y is true or not.

Comment: Take $P:=x=0$ and $Q:=x<1$.

Comment: @nurdyguy "I **only go** the the gym on Tuesday" suggests that you don't go to the cinema on Tuesday, so I think what you mean is "I go the the gym **only on** Tuesday"; but even this second sentence can be ambiguous, because it can be read as Tues being a necessary condition, though not a sufficient condition, for gym, i.e., `gym⇒Tue` instead of `gym⇔Tue`.

Comment: @ryang That's a good point.  The "only go" could be ambiguous.  However, since the context overall was only about if/when I "go to the gym" then whether or not I do anything else that day is inconsequential.

Comment: @nurdyguy You're replying to my bit before the semicolon; "I **only** go to the gym on Tuesday" versus "I go **only** to the gym on Tuesday" versus "I go to the gym **only** on Tuesday".

Comment: @ryang Probably best of all (least likely to be ambiguous) would be something like "The only day of the week I go to the gym is Tuesdays." But in the end, who cares?  This was just a simple example which suited its purpose 5 years ago.  The real question is: Why are you bothering to bring this up now?  Why are you nitpicking a comment on a question from over 5 years ago?

Comment: @nurdyguy No, your latest suggestion is precisely equivalent to what I initially pointed out you meant to say, which, as explained above, can be construed as `gym⇒Tue` rather than clearly your intended `gym⇔Tue`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set theory example: let be $A\subset B$ with $A\ne B$.
$$x\in A\implies x\in B$$
but
$$x\in B\kern.6em\not\kern -.6em \implies x\in A.$$

Almost all the examples of the other answers are particular cases of this.

Answer (score 48):

For real numbers:

$$x > 1$$

implies that 
$$
x^2 > 1
$$

But $x^2 > 1$ does not imply that $x > 1$. For instance, $(-2)^2 = 4 > 1$, but $-2$ is not greater than $1$.

Answer (score 36):

$x = 2 \implies x \ge 2$ is true.

$x \ge 2 \iff x = 2$ is false.

Answer (score 22):

An easy one: all squares are rectangles, but not every rectangle is a square.

The fallacy of the converse is something lots of students are guilty of. Remember, to say P implies Q means that if you have P, you have Q. The presence of Q doesn't mean P holds.

Another example: differentiability implies continuity. Every differentiable function is continuous on its domain's interior, but a continuous function need not have a derivative anywhere.

Comment: Great answer. Just like Martín's set answer but with great examples

Answer (score 11):

$x=2$ implies that $x$ is even.
But $x$ being even does not imply $x=2$.

Answer (score 7):

$$x=-1 \implies x^2 = 1$$
but
$$x=-1 \not\Longleftarrow x^2=1$$
because it could be that $x=1$.

Answer (score 4):

We have:

$$P \leftrightarrow Q \Rightarrow P \rightarrow Q$$

but not

$$P \leftrightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow P \rightarrow Q$$

Answer (score 3):

For example

it always true that

$$a\ge 2 \implies a^2\ge 4$$

but the following does not hold (eg $a=-3$)

$$a\ge 2 \iff a^2\ge 4$$

Comment: No, this is not always true. $a = 1$, $b = -2$ means $a \ge b$ but $a^2 < b^2$.

Comment: @hvd ops of course I had in mind b>0!

Comment: why do I feel like this is copy of the very first answer?

Comment: Maybe because you are wrong? We answered all togheter, please avoid useless considerations and think more to your own behavior here.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine the following:

> $$\begin{align}
> a&=1\\
> \Leftrightarrow a^2&=a\\
> \Leftrightarrow a^2-1&=a-1\\
> \Leftrightarrow (a-1)(a+1)&=a-1\\
> \Leftrightarrow a+1&=1\\
> \Leftrightarrow a&=0
> \end{align}$$
>   Where's the mistake?

In general, $A\Rightarrow B$ means that, in order for $A$ to be true, **it is neccessary** that $B$ is true, but, nothing is neccessary in order for $A$ to be false.

On the other hand, $A\Leftrightarrow B$ means that, in order for $A$ to be true **it is neccessary and sufficient** the $B$ is true. So, when $A$ i true so does $B$ and when $A$ is false, so does $B$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\mbox{[$(x_n)_n$ bounded sequence in $\Bbb R$] $\implies$ [$(x_n)_n$ has a convergent subsequence]}$$

**but the converse is failed** just take $$u_{2n}= 2, ~~~and ~~~u_{2n+1} = n^2$$

the subsequence $(u_{2n})_n$ converges but $ (u_{n})_n$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

In our beginner math classes we often used real world examples to grasp such concepts before starting with mathematical explanations. For this we used the following example:

$$
snow \Rightarrow cold\\
cold \nLeftrightarrow snow
$$

So when it's snowing outside it is definitely cold*. But if it's cold outside, you can not be sure that it is snowing.

<sub>* There are theoretically some [exceptions](http://www.sciencebits.com/SnowAboveFreezing) to this statement, but for the sake of understanding the concept, they can be ignored.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

$x=0 \implies x\neq 1$, but

$x=0 \not \Longleftarrow x\neq 1$, because it is possible that $x=2\neq 0$.